# rank items in sql by dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have movies table with movieID,movieName and movieDate.
I want to select first all movies which added in last 24 hours and order them by date and the rest order by newid().

ie.

1 babylon 28/09/2010 16:00

2.12 monekys 28/09/2010 8:00

3.se7en 25/09/2010 5:00

4.snatch 26/09/2010 18:00

How can i achieve it?

Final answer which is a combination of all other answers which all do something good...

```
declare @date smalldatetime
set @date = dateadd(dd,-2,getdate())

DECLARE @d AS int
SET @d = DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) + 3

   select
    movieID,
    movieTitle,
    movieDate
    from Movies
    order by 
        case 
            when movieDate>@date 
            then movieDate end desc, movieID % @d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one to test.

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN movieDate >= DATEADD(hour, -24, GETDATE()) THEN movieDate END DESC,
  CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (untested):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT -- start with the newest movies
    movieID,
    movieName,
    movieDate,
    1 AS rnk -- new will need it to sort them property
  FROM
    movies
  WHERE
    movieDate >= DATEADD(h, -24, GETDATE()) -- from last 24 hours
  UNION ALL -- there will be no duplicates (so, so)
  SELECT
    movieID,
    movieName,
    movieDate,
    2 AS rnk -- goes after the newest ones
  FROM
    movies
  WHERE
    movieDate < DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()) -- older then 24 hours
 ) AS movies
 ORDER BY
   rnk, 
   CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN movieDate ELSE newid() END -- order by movieDate newest movies and by newid() older ones
```

Are you sure you want to show all movies older then 24 hours?

Also **probably** trick with **modulo** on `movieID` column **will be faster** then using `newid()` function for sorting.

So instead of `newid()` something like:

```
DECLARE @d AS int
SET @d = DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) + 3 -- to avoid division by 0
```

and then in `ORDER` clause instead of `newid()` use `movieID % @d`.

Comment: thanks i will wait for another reply to evaluate performance of each query on my dataset which won't say which answer is wrong but which one performs better with my dataset and it's indexes.

Comment: yep. I want to show all movies just first ones must be new ones and rest randomly ordered. It is for item catalogue

Comment: i haven't checked your query but by reading it there is slight problem with it. It does not sort new movies (in last 24 hours) by add date. If my main index is movieID it doesn't insure that movieID 5 is newer than movieID 4

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN [movieDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
            THEN [movieDate]    
        ELSE [movieID]
    END DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DECLARE @date AS datetime
SET @date = DateAdd(hh, -25, GetDate())

SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    movieID,
    movieName,
    movieData,
    movieDate AS dateToOrder
  FROM
    movies
  WHERE
    movieDate >= DateAdd(h, -24, GetDate())
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    movieID,
    movieName,
    movieData,
    @date AS dateToOrder
  FROM
    movies
  WHERE
    movieDate < DateAdd(hh, -24, GetDate()) -- older then 24 hours
 ) AS movies
 ORDER BY dateToOrder DESC, movieID
```

Comment: +1 for smalldatetime variable instead of using getdate() each time.